# How to output values from a loop into a javascript array

Tags: php, loop, shortcode, javascript, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a custom shortcode in Wordpress. Essentially what I want this to do is the following:

1. Dynamically pull values from a group of Advanced Custom Fields
2. Output those values into a javascript array, comma-separated

Where I'm getting stuck is that I can successfully run a loop over the group of fields and grab all the values and output them on a page. However, when I attempt to store them into a variable to be pulled into a javascript array (`$v` is stored in the `output` variable which is referenced in the `urls` array), it only returns one of those values.

How can I get all the values from the `foreach ( $value as $v)` to list inside of the `urls` array, *with comma separation*? Any help would be appreciated :)

```
add_shortcode('training-player', 'training_player');
// Add shortcode for Diagnostic media playlist
function training_player() {
  $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
  $fields = acf_get_fields(405);
  if( $fields ) {
    echo '<div id="player"></div>';
    foreach( $fields as $field ) {
      $value = get_field( $field['name'], 'user_'. $author_id );
      if(!empty($value)) {
        if ($value) {
          foreach ( $value as $v) {
            echo $v;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    echo "
    <script src='https://luwes.github.io/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.js'></script>
    <script src='https://luwes.github.io/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.playlist.js'></script>
    <script>
      var output = '$v';
      console.log(output)
      vimeowrap('player').setup({
        urls: [
          output
        ],
        plugins: {
          'playlist':{}
        }
      });
    </script>
    ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `$v_all = [];`  before `foreach( $fields as $field )`, replace `foreach ( $value as $v) { ... }` with `$v_all[] = implode(',', $value);`, and above `echo` add `$v = implode(',', $v_all);`.

Comment: Shortcodes should **return** content instead of displaying it.

Comment: @nmr This worked perfectly. Read up on implode after you and the previous poster mentioned it - understanding this a bit more. One _last_ question. What if you wanted to wrap each individual value in quotes. How would you do that?

Comment: [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) or [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). For example: `array_walk( $value, function(&$item) { $item = '"' . $item . '"'; } );`  added before `$v_all[] = implode(',', $value);`.

Comment: @nmr Awesome, that did the trick. You're the best! I think the only thing left for me to figure out is the `output` variable not being being parsed correctly when it's brought into the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Wordpress question.
However you probably need the [implode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) php function, using a comma as glue.

```
foreach( $fields as $field ) {
  $value = get_field( $field['name'], 'user_'. $author_id );
  if(!empty($value)) {
    if ($value) {
      $v = implode(',', $value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry, was thinking in context to Wordpress. Implemented your suggestion. When I echo `$v` from that last if statement, it returns two values, not comma separated. If I console log `$v` from that last if statement, it only returns the last of those values. Why would that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This might get your desired output:

```php
<?php
add_shortcode('training-player', 'training_player');
// Add shortcode for Diagnostic media playlist
function training_player() {
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $fields    = acf_get_fields(405);
    $js_values = [];

    if( $fields ) {
        echo '<div id="player"></div>';
        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            $value = get_field( $field['name'], 'user_'. $author_id );

            if(!empty($value)) {
                if ($value) {
                    foreach ( $value as $v) {
                        $js_values[] = $v;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        echo "
<script src='https://luwes.github.io/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.js'></script>
<script src='https://luwes.github.io/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.playlist.js'></script>
<script>
var output = " . wp_json_encode( $js_values ) . ";
console.log(output)
vimeowrap('player').setup({
urls: [
output
],
plugins: {
'playlist':{}
}
});
</script>
";
    }
}
```

We're storing the value of `$v` in the `$js_values` array, and then outputting it in a format workable with Javascript using `wp_json_encode` instead of trying to directly put it into Javascript.

For future reference, you may want to look at `[wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)` for getting values from PHP to Javascript "the WordPress way", and enqueue the rest of your JS using `[wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script)`, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.